# android.graphics.View invalidate(int, int, int, int) part of a canvas, but onRedraw() the entire canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Android `View` has three versions of `invalidate()`: one that invalidates the whole view, and two that invalidate only a portion of it. But it only has one `onDraw()`, which draws the entire canvas. There must be some use that the system makes of the hint that I only want to invalidate part of the view, but I'm unclear on what it is.

I have a view that does custom drawing in `onDraw()`. Do I have a way to find out which parts of the canvas are invalid, so I only draw those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Android gets ready to render changes to the screen, it does so by creating a union of all of the individual rectangle areas of the screen that need to be redrawn (all the regions that have been invalidated.)

When your view's onDraw(Canvas canvas) method is called, you can check to see if the Canvas has a clip bounds.

If there is a non-empty clip bounds, you can use this information to determine what you will and won't need to draw thus saving time.

If the clip bounds is empty, you should assume Android wants you to draw the entire area of your view.

Something like this:

```
private Rect clipBounds = new Rect();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    boolean isClipped = canvas.getClipBounds(clipBounds);

    // If isClipped == false, assume you have to draw everything
    // If isClipped == true, check to see if the thing you are going to draw is within clipBounds, else don't draw it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  There must be some use that the system makes of the hint that I only want to 
  invalidate part of the view, but I'm unclear on what it is.
```

Yes, it is. The method invalidate (int l, int t, int r, int b) has four parameters which are used by the View's parent View to calculate the mLocalDirtyRect which is a filed of the View class. And the mLocalDirtyRect is used by the getHardwareLayer() method in the View class, here is its description:

```
 /**
     * <p>Returns a hardware layer that can be used to draw this view again
     * without executing its draw method.</p>
     *
     * @return A HardwareLayer ready to render, or null if an error occurred.
     */
    HardwareLayer getHardwareLayer() {
```

Means that Android can refresh part of your view without call the View's onDraw() method. So you don't need to try drawing part of the View yourself, because Android will do it for you when you tell it the dirty part of your View.

Finally, I think you can refer to the source code of View and ViewGroup for more details, here is the link that you can read them online:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java